# Is there a place for research paper discussion?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I understand that Stack Overflow is not for questions that cannot be answered, so I want to know, where should I raise discussion about a research paper and possibly ask questions about the paper?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kind of paper, on what topic? Discussion probably isn't going to be on topic anywhere on this network, but a specific question could be appropriate if there's an existing site that matches your topic: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: If the paper is about algorithm, I think asking in theoretical computer science is ok but I need to be very specific for my question. Email the author is an option but I think a lot of people have come across the same problem so a discussion forum is a good place. I just cannot find this site.

Comment: Well then this question might be better asked, with more detail on the specific question you want to ask, on https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/, where they can tell you if it's on topic for their site. If you want to know somewhere off the Stack Exchange network you can have a discussion, it's not the job of any of these Meta sites to find it for you.

Comment: Generally the authors of research papers are open for questions and have a way you can contact them, probably through email.

Comment: What about [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 9):

Nowhere, unfortunately. None of the sites in the Stack Exchange network are designed for discussion, and they do not accept open-ended questions that do not have answers. It simply isn't a place you can go for a round-table discussion about your research paper.

There probably are websites *outside* of Stack Exchange where you can do this, but I'm not an expert on any of those. An academic conference would be the ideal forum. If you can't find one relevant to your specialization or area of interest, then consider organizing one of your own.

On the other hand, if there's a *specific* topic that you have an *answerable* question about, regardless of whether it originates from a research paper, then you could probably find a Stack Exchange site where that is on-topic. Stack Overflow accepts questions about programming and algorithms as they relate to practical programming problems. [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) accepts more general questions about algorithms and other topics in computer science. [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) accepts questions about practical problems in software engineering, including methodology, architecture, design, etc. There is a complete listing of other sites available [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).